# Import JavaScript files - PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, mobile, cordova

I'm developing a web application that will be supported in multiple OS and I'm planing to use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) in order to get access to the [system features](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/index.html).

I've downloaded PhoneGap 1.5.0 and there's a specific JavaScript file for each of the supported OS, do I need to check the device information in order to load the correct file(s)?

Anyway I'm still a bit confuse why there's no file on iOS library folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've downloaded PhoneGap 1.5.0 and there's a specific JavaScript file for each of the supported OS, do I need to check the device information in order to load the correct file(s)?

No you do not need to check any device information.Your code is reusable for all platforms.You just need to keep in mind that you need to use the cordova.js file separately for all the mobile platforms. What i mean is when you download phonegap then you will get different folder libraries for Android, Blackberry, iOS etc.. You just have to copy cordova.js from Android folder if you are going for android development and in a same manner for others....

> Anyway I'm still a bit confuse why there's no file on iOS library folder?
>   build your application

What file are you talking about?
In the iOS phonegap folder there is a .dmg file. You need to install that file on your MAC and then in xcode you will get a Cordova based Application template... From there you can create phonegap applications.

Comment: Coder_sLaY but I still need to check the device in order to know which files should be imported, right? In relation to the iOS that means that I can't use PhoneGap Build?

Comment: @Diogo Currently work is going on to make cordova.js as a universal thing for all platforms.. But for now You just have to use different cordova.js which was provided in the phonegap build. For example. I have created an application for Android using Cordova... And my application works fine for iOS... I just had to change my android cordova.js with iOS cordova.js...Rest was the same... :)

Comment: @Coder_sLaY can you provide a link to the build version of cordova.js?

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap is used to create "hybrid" apps - not pure "web apps".

While you develop using HTML, you actually generate native apps. PhoneGap provides wrappers and bridging code to map your HTML app to a standard mobile native app.

You use a different phonegap.js (or cordova.js) for each platform (Android, iOS, etc.)

Note, that an upcoming Cordova release will unify cordova.js into a single file for all the platforms. However, you'll still create a separate native app for each one.